# How do I debug python code by passing by a yaml file in Pycharm

Tags: debugging, pycharm

I would like to debug my python code by passing yml file in Pycharm. Appreciate it if you can tell me how to do that.

I tried putting my yml file in parameters under Run > Edit Configuration. But eventually it runs as Run, not in debug mode that i wanted, coz it didn't stop where i put the breakpoints in my code. Thanks in advance.